# Обнуление базы данных на postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Подскажите, как правильно удалить все записи из всех таблиц базы, при этом не удалив сами таблицы?

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables

TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
```

c постгре работал четыре года назад на дельфи, надеюсь без ошибок.
запрос второй строчки в цикле естественно надо сделать по результатам первого.

может кто работает с ней сейчас напишет запрос одной строчкой)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:
Сделать дамп схемы, дропнуть всю схему, восстановить из дампа.

```
pg_dump --schema-only БД > БД.dump
dropdb БД
psql -f БД.dump БД
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
delete from table_name;
(здесь можно условие типа where customer_id=1 and god = 2010)
```